# Xamarin Binding Grid to ViewModel

Tags: c#, xamarin, binding, grid

Is there any way to bind the properties of a grid (rowdefinitions, columndefintions, rowspacing, columnspacing, etc.) to a ViewModel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It always help to look at the source code: https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/blob/master/Xamarin.Forms.Core/Grid.cs#L20

So it does look like rowdefinitions, columndefintions, rowspacing, columnspacing, are bindable properties as evidenced by the code:

```
    public static readonly BindableProperty RowSpacingProperty = BindableProperty.Create("RowSpacing", ...);

    public static readonly BindableProperty ColumnSpacingProperty = BindableProperty.Create("ColumnSpacing", ...);

    public static readonly BindableProperty ColumnDefinitionsProperty = BindableProperty.Create("ColumnDefinitions", ...);

    public static readonly BindableProperty RowDefinitionsProperty = BindableProperty.Create("RowDefinitions", ...);
```

**UPDATE:** So here is what needs to be done to make this binding work:

If using a [Bindings Value Converter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/data-binding/converters), make sure it never returns null.

Then, protect against any binding resolution by assigning the Grid's `TargetNullValue` and `FallbackValue` to an empty Row/ColumnDefinitionCollection (using, e.g., a StaticResource).

To do this, first make a [static resource](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/xaml/resource-dictionaries#creating-and-consuming-a-resourcedictionary) that is just a Row/ColumnDefinitionCollection in App.xaml:

```
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <RowDefinitionCollection x:Key="NullRowDefs" />
        <ColumnDefinitionCollection x:Key="NullColDefs" />
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

Then set the `TargetNullValue` and the `FallbackValue` properties of the Grid to the above static resources:

```
 <Grid RowDefinitions="{Binding RowSize, TargetNullValue={StaticResource NullRowDefs}, FallbackValue={StaticResource NullRowDefs}}"
       ColumnDefinitions="{Binding ColumnSize, TargetNullValue={StaticResource NullColDefs}, FallbackValue={StaticResource NullColDefs}}"
       x:Name="grid">
```

Doing the above should resolve the `ArgumentException`.

**UPDATE:** This binding should work without supplying the `TargetNullValue` and `FallbackValue`. A [bug](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/4537#issuecomment-442740506) was discovered and a [PR](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/pull/4541) has been created, so this should be fixed in an upcoming release, but in the meantime, use the workaround.

Comment: I've tried binding the Row and Column definitions in xaml to a Row/ColumnDefinitionCollection, but I keep getting "System.ArgumentException: Value was an invalid value for RowDefinitions". Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: Oh, looks like there is an old bug report about this: https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=56618. I could make RowSpacing and ColumnSpacing bindings work, but got the same exception as you when trying to use bindings for RowDefinitions and COlumnDefinitions.